# Installing Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.10, but I also want to install Windows 7 and be able to dual-boot.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall Windows 7 recently, and your situation is similar, so here's an overview: shrink and partition or reformat one of your current non-Ubuntu partitions, install Windows 7, then recover Grub2.

Create a live USB of Ubuntu using [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). Alter your boot order from BIOS and boot into the live USB.

Open up GParted (or install it with **sudo apt-get install gparted** from terminal). Create an NTFS partition either by resizing/formatting an existing partition, or shrinking your current Ubuntu partition (not preferred).

Now, remove your live USB, insert Windows 7 install disc and reboot into Windows 7 installer. Follow through the installation procedure, making sure to select the NTFS partition you just created above as the Windows install location.

Once the Windows install is done, you will find that Ubuntu is not accessible. Again, reboot into the Ubuntu live USB/disk and follow [these steps](http://fosswire.com/post/2009/05/restoring-overwritten-grub/) to recover your Grub2 boot menu.

Reboot and you will find Grub2 back in all its glory, with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu as options. You can use Grub Customizer to tweak the order of the boot menu entries.

If you have any issues, try searching here on Askubuntu or any search engine, and if you don't find satisfactory answers, leave a comment below!